# Is reframing a slice in Go a constant-time operation?

Tags: go, memory, time-complexity, slice

I have a FIFO queue of coordinate pairs (`[x, y]`) in Go:

```
type Copair [2]int
type Queue []Copair
var q = Queue{ ... preloaded values ... }
```

The API is defined as follows, with the important piece being the `pop()` function:

```
func (q Queue) push(p Copair) {
    q = append(q, p)
}

func (q Queue) pop() (error, Copair) {
    if q != nil && len(q) >= 1 {
        q = q[1:]
        return nil, q[0]
    } else {
        return errors.New("index out of range [0]"), nil
    }
}
```

In that `q = q[1:]` I'm reframing the slice, which in theory should only require one address to be changed in memory, and therefore be a constant-time operation. Now granted, we're gradually losing bytes on the heap (or who knows, Go's escape analysis might be smart enough to put it on the stack), and I'd hope the garbage collector can reclaim these bytes to avoid a memory leak, and eventually we're going to hit the heap boundary and the runtime will have to copy the whole queue elsewhere which will definitely be a linear-time operation. But...

Is the slice reframe carried out by `q = q[1:]` a constant-time operation, or is it linear with the size of the queue? If (as I suspect) the answer is the oh-so-very-Go *"it depends"*, what are the conditions it depends on, and are there any easy rules of thumb for figuring this out?

Comment: "should only require one address to be changed in memory" it requires one value to be changed, but it's not an address, it's an index. "I'd hope the garbage collector can reclaim these bytes" no, it cannot; the slice is a reference to an underlying array, the the size of that array is not changing, only the window the slice covers.

Comment: See also https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/8 and https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Comment: May I ask for some constructive feedback on why this is being downvoted? It seems a perfectly reasonable question, and I'd love to be able to improve my questions in the future if there's some big mistake I'm making :)

Answer (score 7):

Slicing is a constant time operation. A slice header contains the pointer to the underlying array, size, and capacity. The operation `q:=q[1:]` simply create a new header with an adjusted array pointer, size and capacity.

Answer (score 3):

The `q[1:]` is a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), it does "nothing more" than creating a new slice header, which is [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader). It's just 3 integer values.

Index bounds are checked of course, and e.g. if the `q` slice is empty, it would result in a runtime panic.

Comment: Hmm, this changes things. So what about the underlying memory? At what point does the GC see the dropped indices in the slice no longer have references to them?

Comment: A slice refers to a contiguous portion of a backing array. As long as there is a slice header pointing to some parts of the backing array, the whole backing array will be kept in memory. When there is no more reference to it, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: So because in this case the slice header is being updated but the underlying array is only growing, this is just a rather elegant memory leak?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist No, this isn't a leak. Popping will change the slice header to exclude the beginning of the array, but pushing elements will append to the end. Once the backing array is insufficient for append, `append()` allocates a new backing array, and copies over the content, only the part covered by the slice, the beginning, abandoned, part will not be copied. After such a copy the old backing array can be garbage collected. So if you keep using the queue, pushing, popping, new allocations will naturally free the unused, beginning part.